# Why the column order is changing while appending pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I want to append (merge) all the csv files in a folder using Python pandas.

For example: Say folder has two csv files `test1.csv` and `test2.csv` as follows:

```
A_Id    P_Id    CN1         CN2         CN3
AAA     111     702         709         740
BBB     222     1727        1734        1778
```

and

```
A_Id    P_Id    CN1         CN2         CN3
CCC     333     710        750          750
DDD     444     180        734          778
```

So the python script I wrote was as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd
import glob

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("testfolder/*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df)

all_data.to_csv('testfolder/combined.csv')
```

Though the `combined.csv` seems to have all the appended rows, it looks as follows:

```
      CN1       CN2         CN3    A_Id    P_Id
  0   710      750         750     CCC     333
  1   180       734         778     DDD     444     
  0   702       709         740     AAA     111
  1  1727       1734        1778    BBB     222
```

Where as it should look like this:

```
A_ID   P_Id   CN1    CN2    CN2
AAA    111    702    709    740
BBB    222    1727   1734   1778
CCC    333    110    356    123
DDD    444    220    256    223
```

- **Why are the first two columns moved to the end?**
- **Why is it appending in the first line rather than at the last line?**

What am I missing? And how can I get get of 0s and 1s in the first column?

P.S: Since these are large csv files, I thought of using pandas.

Comment: What version of pandas use? Because it works in 0.17.0 well.

Comment: I think problem is with format of csv - try after row `df = pd.read_csv(f)` add `print df.head()` for checking it.

Comment: And I think you read output as input `glob.glob("testfolder/*.csv"):`, because output is write to input directory: `all_data.to_csv('testfolder/combined.csv')`, you have to change directory to `all_data.to_csv('out/combined.csv')`

Comment: You can get away `0` and `1` by adding parameter `index=False` `all_data.to_csv('out/combined.csv', index=False)`

Comment: You could sort the inputfiles on file name: `for f in sorted(glob.glob("testfolder/*.csv")):`   .This will read test1.csv before test2.csv, and make sure the rows are in the right order...

Comment: @RolfSchorpion In reality the filenames are random numbers :(

Comment: The columns can be sorted before writing to csv: `all_data = all_data[['A_Id','P_Id','CN1','CN2','CN3']]`

Comment: @RolfSchorpion Oh, I didn't think of it. However, I did some changes and it is answered by myself below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tweaked the code as below. Comments in-line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd
import glob

# Grab all the csv files in the folder to a list.
fileList = glob.glob('input_folder/*.csv')

#Initialize an empty dataframe to grab the csv content.
all_data = pd.DataFrame()

#Initialize an empty list to grab the dataframes.
dfList= []

for files in  fileList:
    df =  pd.read_csv(files, index_col = None, header= False)
    dfList.append(df)

#The frames will be in reverse order i.e last read file's content in the begining. So reverse it again
Reversed_dfList =  dfList[::-1]
CombinedFrame =  pd.concat(Reversed_dfList)

# The "Combined.csv" file will have combination of all the files.
CombinedFrame.to_csv('output_folder/Combined.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 27):

Try this .....

```
all_data = all_data.append(df)[df.columns.tolist()]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: So is this perhaps a Pandas bug that needs to be filed? I had the same issue.

Comment: the question @kingmakerking was asking is "why". this would not help if the 2 dataframes would have different columns for instance. I can see the same issue with pd.concat as well

Comment: If `all_data` had more columns than `df`, this will omit the columns that are not present in `df`.

Answer (score 15):

Starting from version 0.23.0, you can prevent the `append()` method to sort the final appended DataFrame. In your case:

```
all_data = all_data.append(df, sort=False)
```

Comment: This also works now for concat. `df = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort=False)`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Does this work for anyone else?

Comment: @msarafzadeh: it works fine in pandas 0.25.3. Always always state your version number, when you're reporting version-dependent issues. Did you use the pandas-dev stream from git, or a release (which?)

Comment: As of Pandas `v1.0`, `sort=False` is the default. However, this problem still seems to occur...

Answer (score 6):

You can use [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to change to the original order:

```
all_data = all_data.append(df)
all_data = all_data.reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

I saw this here (more details in the link): https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/4588#issuecomment-44421883

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and it was painfull. I managed to solve it by reorganising columns based on source dataframe after it was appended to final dataframe. It would look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pandas as pd
import glob

all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("testfolder/*.csv"):
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df)
    all_data = all_data[df.columns]

all_data.to_csv('testfolder/combined.csv')
```

Since your issue was from almost two years ago, I'm posting solution which worked for me for enyone else who will also face similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

`df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(Added_rows).T)`

Answer (score 0):

if you create the dataframe and you set the columns the way you want then append will comply to this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['d','b','a','c'])
df = df.append({'d': name,
                        'b': h,
                        'a': w,
                        'c': normal_size                        
                        }
                       , ignore_index=True,sort=False)
```

Answer (score -1):

`all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)`

Put **ignore_index=True** so the order will not change.
By default is `False` so you need to change that.